# Jquery Animate Background Image Sway On Hover Not Working In Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, hover, jquery-animate, background-image

I by no means have even a cursory understanding of jQuery or Javascript. I am however very adept at coding in HTML, CSS and some basic PHP.

I have struggled for too many hours to hack together a little code block that animates a background image on hover/off hover.

I see now it does not work in Firefox because supposedly FF does not accept background-position-y (or x?).

I have read up here as much as possible and I cannot seem to implement any fix that has been suggested in previous posts.

Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarcello/3TGTB/26/
It can also be seen live here: http://www.buenolisto.com/alma

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If some one can amend the code in a simple light weight fashion that I can understand and that would get the job done I would be foreever grateful.

If you need me to drop the code in here directly just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Coupla things- try assigning a class to DOM objects, not changing CSS on the fly with jQuery. then, add/remove class w/ jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support background-position-x, background-position-y, nor is it in the specification ([It got rejected](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/9))
You should consider another approach as suggested by ahren

Answer (score 2):

What about a different approach altogether?

http://jsfiddle.net/Aaqp7/